# Change Window Server 2012 R2 IP Address, Subnet mask, Gateway in C#

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012-r2

I created c# console application to change IP Address, Subnet mask and Gateway.
It's work good on window 8.1 Enterprise but It not working on Window server 2012 R2. And this is my code.

```
public bool setIP(string ip_address, string subnet_mask)
    {
        ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
        {
            if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject setIP;
                    ManagementBaseObject newIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");

                    newIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { ip_address };
                    newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnet_mask };

                    setIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to set IP");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

public bool setGateway(string gateway)
    {
        ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
        {
            if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject setGateway;
                    ManagementBaseObject newGateway =
                        objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");

                    newGateway["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { gateway };
                    newGateway["GatewayCostMetric"] = new int[] { 1 };

                    setGateway = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", newGateway, null);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to set Gateway");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Please, Give me some suggestion.

Comment: Are you running the console app using "Run as administrator"?

Comment: Yes of course. But still not working.

Comment: you might try the WMI trouble shooting guide here, and let us know if all these steps succeeded.  http://www.solarwinds.com/documentation/apm/docs/APMWMITroubleshooting.pdf